# cygwin, how to set up to get unix shell, and c program, to do systems programming?

Tags: unix, installation, cygwin

Which packages do you download to attain VI option, and shell, and do c programming in it?

Comment: Why use Cygwin? Why not use an actual Unix-like system (e.g. Linux) in a virtual machine?

Comment: I see that to date you've asked 14 questions and haven't accepted any answers. If you want to have people keep on answering your questions, it would be a good idea to accept some of those answers.

Answer (score 2):

vim (vi - improved) is in the Editors category.

bash (shell) is in the Base category.

GNU C is in the Devel category. I'd suggest downloading the GDB debugger and `make` from that category too.

All of these (and much more) can be selected from the Cygwin `setup` program at [www.cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com).